# Convert a Range to Array

Tags: excel, vba

I have a Problem with my code.I want to get all Cells and to put These in an Array but it didnt work. Runtime Error 13.
Range -> Array

```
For z = 0 To 3
Worksheets(Tabellen(z)).Select
AnzahlZellen = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A"))
    For n = 1 To AnzahlZellen

        'Worksheets(Tabellen(z)).Select'
        Range("A" & n).Select
        InhaltsArray(n) = Range("A" & n).Value
```

Comment: Can you work with a 2-D array?

Answer (score 1):

In this case you could build a one-dimensioal array like that

```
Dim vDat as variant
Dim rg as range
Set rg = Range("A1:A" & AnzahlZellen)
vDat = WorksheetFunction.Transpose((rg))
```

In this way you can easily read from a range of cells to an array. You can also write from an array to a range of cells. Usually you get a 2D-array but as you only have one column you can convert it by Transpose into a 1D-array.

As you did not show the declaration of InhaltsArray I guess the [run time error 13](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/type-mismatch-error-13) is caused by some content of the range which does not fit the data type of InhaltsArray

As an additional comment to your code: Most of the time you do not need [select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to store 4 worksheets' column A values into a single 1-D array,

```
dim i as long, n as long, z as long, tmp as variant

for z=lbound(Tabellen) to ubound(Tabellen)

    with Worksheets(Tabellen(z))
        if z=lbound(Tabellen) then
            InhaltsArray = application.transpose(.range(.cells(1, "A"), .cells(.rows.count, "A").end(xlup)).value2
        else
            tmp = .range(.cells(1, "A"), .cells(.rows.count, "A").end(xlup)).value2
            i = ubound(InhaltsArray)
            redim preserve InhaltsArray(lbound(InhaltsArray) to (i + ubound(tmp, 1)))
            for n = lbound(tmp, 1) to ubound(tmp, 1)
                InhaltsArray(i + n) = tmp(n, 1)
            next n
        end if

    end with

next z
```

Answer (score 0):

The Answer submitted by @Storax is the basis for the following code, which defines function `rangeToArray` that will take a `Range` object and return an equivalent `array`:

```
Function rangeToArray(rg As Range)
  If rg.Count = 1 Then
    rangeToArray = Array(rg(1))
  Else
    rangeToArray = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(rg)
  End If
End Function
```

It can be used like so:

```
Sub test()
  Dim lastRowInA As Long, i As Integer

  Dim a()

  lastRowInA = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A"))
  
  a = rangeToArray(Range("A1:A" & lastRowInA))

  For i = 1 To lastRowInA
    Debug.Print a(i)
  Next

End Sub
```

The `if` inside `rangeToArray` is necessary only if `rg` could consist of a single cell.

Also, if `A` has no populated rows, an error will result when using `lastRowInA`, which will be `0`, to define the range being passed to`rangeToArray`.

The single line from Storax, shown below and adapted in the `Else` in function `rangeToArray`, is a brilliant, simple key to solution.

```
vDat = WorksheetFunction.Transpose((rg))
```

---